# Smooth scrolling?

Tags: front-end

Is there any way to achieve smoother scrolling than this:

[image]

Why can't notebooks scroll like chrome or safari? I'm using OSX 11.1 on macOS 10.12.4.

Comment: It looks like problems of interaction of MMa with X-server on your Mac. I've seen something similar on some builds of Linux..

Comment: @Rom38 There is not X server involved on the Mac.

Comment: Why don't you ask Wolfram Support?  The more people complain, the more likely that this issue will be prioritized.  I think the problem is related to two things: 1. large and complex graphics objects that are slow to render 2. a non-optimal redraw strategy: that graphics is re-rendered more often than needed.  As you noticed, the Mathematica front end fell significantly behind browsers. It wasn't always so. To be fair, browser makes have *a lot* more resources and manpower to develop their software. But still: the  M front end could be faster.

Comment: Had that exact problem for all 10.xx versions. Was so bad I had to use page up and down to scroll through a large notebook. Then it disappeared with 11.0. I hope it has not made a comeback in 11.1...

Comment: @Szabolcs, Ok, let's call it XQuartz instead X11 :) There is typical headache for Unix clones - the interaction of X-server with certain applications..

Comment: Which version of MMA and Mac/OS are you using?

Comment: @Rom38 Yes, there are X servers available for Mac, as they are for Windows. But most applications don't use them. Mathematica certainly doesn't, and works without an X server installed. I don't think this problem has anything to do with X servers, or that Mathematica on Mac is comparable in this respect with Mathematica on Linux.

Comment: Something important I forgot: check `$Version`.  Check that the date is March 16. If it is March 13, re-download Mathematica and re-install it please.  Let me know if this fixed it.

Comment: @Szabolcs, As I know, all windows-based interfaces in Unix-like systems are using certain X-server. Mathematica in console can be launched without X-server but the front-end needs it anyway..

Comment: You did not state your version.  Can you check if it is the March 13 or the March 16 one?  I had the March 13 one originally, and it had serious graphics performance problems. Those are resolved in the March 16 release.

Comment: @Rom38 The problem has nothing to do with X servers. My suggestion is this:  in the preferences, go to "Appearance >  Graphics" and set "Antialiasing quality" to "No Antialiasing". If this works, it could be a problem with the OpenGL engine.

Answer (score 5):

Here is something you might try. It made the scrolling behavior much better for me, although it could still be improved:

Open the `Preferences` menu and make the adjustment shown in the screen shot here:

[image: prefs]

This selects `No Antialiasing`. On my Mac laptop, the scrolling is significantly improved.

Comment: This has influence on rendering of namely graphical objects. But these settings does not change the jumps during the scrolling of the code in front-end.

Comment: Yes this has no effect