# Mathematica 11.0 3D plotting bug?

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug affecting** (at least) ***Mathematica* 11.0.0.0 to 11.2 for Win7**

---

Trying to draw a 2D line on a 3D plot starts to behave strangely as I let the line get long.  Is the following a bug, or am I doing something wrong?  (This is a minimal working example of an issue encountered in a more complicated situation)

```
plot = Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
line = ParametricPlot3D[{0, 0, t}, {t, -1*^5, 1*^5}, PlotStyle -> Thick];
Show[plot, line]
```

[image: power=5 line works]

Changing the length of the line...

```
plot = Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
line = ParametricPlot3D[{0, 0, t}, {t, -1*^10, 1*^10}, PlotStyle -> Thick];
Show[plot, line]
```

[image: power=10 line bugged]

Further, when the plot is then rotated along the z-axis the displayed plane does not rotate with the rest of the plot space.  It just stretches to always reach the edges of the box.  Rotating it along the x- or y-axes does rotate the plane. 
 Something seems extremely fishy here.

Comment: On Mac with 11.0.1 I don't see the strange behavior shown in the second plot. Both look almost the same here, except that the second plot has a small and not fully rendered piece of the line sticking out above the 3D box of the plot. One thing I changed system-wide on my Mac that could have an influence is [described here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141285/245). What is your OS?

Comment: @Jens I'm working on Win 7 with Mathematica 11.0.0.0

Comment: OK, I guess then it would be good to hear from Windows users if this is a bug that has perhaps been fixed in the newer versions...

Comment: I upgraded to mathematica 11.1.1.0 and the issue persists.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I would report it as a bug to http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback

Comment: I can reproduce this on win7 with 11.0.1 and 11.1.1. I would also suggest to report it as a bug...

Comment: I have reported this to Wolfram.  Thanks, all.

Comment: Reproduced with version 11.2.0 on Win7 x64. What the support replied?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Wolfram support confirmed the bug, and passed the report to the developers.

Comment: No issue on MMA 11.2 Linux.

Answer (score 1):

```
$VersionNumber = 11.1
```

I was having a similar graphical issue and was trying your workaround. I'm running the latest version of MMA on the cloud and unforuately I'm not able to reproduce your error. Hopefully this helps.

```
plot = Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
line = ParametricPlot3D[{0, 0, t}, {t, -1*^10, 1*^10}, PlotStyle -> Thick];
Show[plot, line]
```

[image: graphic example]

Answer (score 1):

```
line = Graphics3D[InfiniteLine[{0, 2, 10}, {1, 1, 40}]];
```

If use this the problem does not happen.

Comment: But not the same plot.

Comment: mo, it's not same sorry. I have same issue and tries to bypass the ParametricPlot to understand